# Web service to Xcode encryption

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services, encryption, aes

I am trying encrypt data on an iPhone and send up the encrypted text to a web service for them to decrypt it. If the decryption works then it returns the First name in the xml as a confirmation things worked. Here is my Xcode

Note: *The 'key' is the same in both xcode and web service*

The information I want encrypted:

```
NSString *fnameencrypted = [[NSString alloc] AES256EncryptWithKey:f_name.text withKey:key]];    
NSString *lnameencrypted = [[NSString alloc] AES256EncryptWithKey:l_name.text withKey:key]];
```

The NSString method

```
-(NSString *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)plaintext withKey:(NSString *)key{
    NSData *plainData = [plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSData *encryptedData = [plainData AES256EncryptWithKey:key];  
    NSString *encryptedString = [encryptedData base64Encoding];
    return encryptedString;
}
```

***EDIT***

The encryption method

```
-(NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key{
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);
    if(cryptStatus == kCCSuccess){
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer
    return nil;
}
```

Here is my web service code

```
private static string Decrypt(string encryptedText, string completeEncodedKey, int keySize)
{
    RijndealManaged aesEncryption = new RijndealManaged();
    aesEncryption.KeySize = keySize; //keySize is 256
    aesEncryption.BlockSize = 128;
    aesEncryption.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    aesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aesEncryption.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ACSII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(completeEncodedString)).Split(',')[0]);
    aesEncryption.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ACSII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(completeEncodedString)).Split(',')[1]);
    ICryptoTransform decrypto = aesEncryption.CreateDecryptor();
    byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(encryptedText.ToCharArray(), 0, encryptedText.Length);
    return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(decrypto.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
}
```

This code does not work because it returns

```
<response><return>0</return></response>
```

Comment: Where are you getting your initialization vector from? When you encrypted, you didn't use one. Are the key and IV definitely correct on the web service side?

Comment: Use better crypto classes. For one, the key should be NSData, not NSString!

Comment: I agree with @tc. that the Java classes seem strange that they're taking strings for the key and IV. Also, along those same lines, you might want to use a better key, for example take the SHA256 hash of the user supplied key and actually use that as your AES encryption key.

Comment: @JasonCoco: That's not Java, and SHA-256 is a **very bad** key-derivation function. See [scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html).

Comment: @tc. Ah, you're right, not Java, I didn't look closely at it, definitely not objective-c tho (on the server side). I know sha256 isn't great, but it's far better than using a few bytes of a pass-phrase as a key, which is what he's doing now.

Comment: @tc. I just realized he's passing the key with the data >_< I thought it was just some secret known to both ends but not passed... when I suggested the SHA256 it was just to get a better key from the shared phrase, not to obscure the actual key for transit or storage.

Comment: @Jason: It's *almost entirely equivalent* to using a few bytes as the key, since the time taken to do SHA-256 is negligible. **Hashing adds no entropy.**

Comment: @tc. You are, of course, absolutely correct.

Comment: I have created a encrypt on the server side and a decrypt on the iPhone side and they encrypt and decrypt fine. I am starting to think it is something to do with the `aesEncryption.IV` and `aesEncryption.Key` not being the same. If anyone can help that would be great.